# ActiveRecord: scope with a lambda applied on top of has_many Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

  scope :user, ->(user) { where('user_id = ?', user.id) }
  scope :owner, ->(user) { where('owner_id = ?', user.id) }
  scope :active, where(is_active: true)
end
```

If I type the following in the console I have:

```
Transaction.user(User.first).class # ActiveRecord::Transaction OK
User.first.transactions.class # Array KO
User.first.transactions.active.class # ActiveRecord::Transaction OK
User.first.transactions.where(used_id: User.first.id).class # ActiveRecord::Transaction OK
User.first.transactions.owner(User.first) # ERROR: 

NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<User:0x00000007d7d528>
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activemodel-3.2.21/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb:19:in `to'
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):14
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/augustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:40:in `require'
    from script/rails:40:in `<main>'
```

And the craziest thing is that:

```
User.first.transactions.active.owner(User.first)
```

Works!!

I'm using Rails 3.2 so pretty old I know, but still, annoying, right?

Questions are:

- Shouldn't `User.first.transactions.class` be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?
- Why does the error occurs at `User.first.transactions.owner(User.first)`? Is it an ActiveRecord bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Doesn't annoy me....What's your question?

Comment: Can you tell what you are trying to do with this query `User.first.transactions.active.owner(User.first)`?

Comment: Since a similar query (scope applied on top of `has_many`) works fine in Rails 4, I'm pretty sure it's one of the fixed issues since 3.2.

Comment: Yes, it is scope with a lambda applied on top of `has_many` actually. With `scope :myscope, where()` works

Comment: I doubt, it got confused with the `owner` association and `owner` scope name.. can you change one name to something else and try... ?

Answer (score 1):

1. `rails console` does something special with associations, it will immediately "load" them so they are turned into Arrays.
2. I think you might have a naming clash. You have associations `user` and `owner` and define scopes with the same names. I usually use class methods, but I would also opt for a little more meaningful names (avoiding the name clash).

So I would write something like:

```
 def self.from_user(user)
   where(user_id: user.id)
 end

 def self.owned_by(user)
   where(owner_id: user.id)
 end
```

I am not sure the cause of your error is the naming or because you use the scope method.

Comment: The names aren't actually the correct ones, but an example. I'll definitely try it with class methods, though I always find scopes more elegant. Maybe `rails console` does some tweaking, but I do reproduce the error within my app (that how I found out about it).